# Array in console is not empty, but array[0] is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

in my function, I get the data from my firestore database.
I recover the data from the table 'perturbations' and the data from the table 'trajetsFavorite'.
what I want to do is retrieve the field 'numero' from the disturbance collection and assign it to a array 'numeroPertrubationsFavorite' and recover the field 'numero' from the collection 'trajetsFavorites' and assign it to the array 'numeroTrajetsFavorite'.
Then I read my 2 array,
If the 2 fields are equal, I set my variable 'isPerturbationsFavorite' to true.
I tried a code that does this, when I make a console.log (this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite), the data is well filled in the array, also for the console.log (this.numeroTrajetsFavorite) the data is displayed well too .
However when I do a console.log (this.numeroPerturbationsFavorites[0].numero, it's undefined.
Can anybody help me? I think it's probably because of synchronous and asynchronous but I don't know how it works.

i put my code here:

```
  getPerturbationFavorite(){
        console.log(this.perturbationsBDD); //this is the variable to which i assign the data from the perturbation collection
        console.log(this.trajetFavorisBDD); //this is the variable to which i assign the data from the trajetFavorite collection

        this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite.length = 0;
        this.numeroTrajetFavorite.length = 0;
        this.perturbationsBDD.subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
            console.log('super' + res[i].numero);
            this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite.push({
              numero : res[i].numero
            });
          }
        })

        this.trajetFavorisBDD.subscribe((res) => {
          for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
            console.log(res[i].numero);
            this.numeroTrajetFavorite.push({
              numero : res[i].numero
            });
          }
        })

        console.log(this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite); // display the data
        console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite); // display the data
        console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite[0].numero) //display undefined


      for(let i = 0; i < this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite.length; i++){
        console.log(this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite[i].numero); // dont display

        for(let a = 0; a < this.numeroTrajetFavorite.length; a++){
          console.log(this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite[i].numero); // dont display
          console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite[i].numero); // dont display
          if(this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite[i].numero === this.numeroTrajetFavorite[a].numero){

            this.isPerturbationsFavorite = true;
            console.log(this.isPerturbationsFavorite); // dont display
          }else{
            this.isPerturbationsFavorite = false;
            console.log(this.isPerturbationsFavorite); // dont display
          }
        }
      }
      }
```

[image: this is the error]

in this picture there is the error and on the top of error there is the two array result

Comment: Define a function that will do the stuff at the bottom(for inside for code part) and call the function inside the subscribe method.

Comment: @Ramesh i don't really undestertand, you think that i make another function and i put this code the 'for()' and  into and in my function getPerturbationsFavorite() i call this function after the two subscribe ?

Comment: Update the question with what is displayed in the console.

Comment: The property `numero` cannot be read and the array of objecs `numeroTrajetFavorite` that you declared is undefined. Did you get to try any of the answers from below?

Comment: I tested what I could but I can't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Angular, I would highly recommend you to make use of [RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) operators, which is by default installed in Angular.

Within your `getPerturbationFavorite` method, you will need to wait for both `this.perturbationsBDD` and `this.trajetFavorisBDD` observables to be completed, before any other dependent operations are carried out.

You may make use of the [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) operator for this purpose, which will emit the last emitted value from each observable. This way, the subsequent values will not be `undefined`.

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

getPerturbationFavorite(){
  this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite.length = 0;
  this.numeroTrajetFavorite.length = 0;

  combineLatest(this.perturbationsBDD, this.trajetFavorisBDD).subscribe([res1, res2] => {
    for(let i = 0; i < res1.length; i++){
      this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite.push({
        numero : res1[i].numero
      });
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < res2.length; i++){
      this.numeroTrajetFavorite.push({
        numero : res2[i].numero
      });
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite.length; i++){
      for(let a = 0; a < this.numeroTrajetFavorite.length; a++) {
        if(this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite[i].numero === this.numeroTrajetFavorite[a].numero) {
          this.isPerturbationsFavorite = true;
        } else {
          this.isPerturbationsFavorite = false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i understood the principle, but i think there is a bug in your code, because there is many warming, mainly on the for loop, on res.length . I tested res1.length but that didn't work also for res2.length. Did you have an idea for that ? thank you

Comment: Also if i do just a console.log(res1) and console.log(res2), the browser doesn't display anything. Did you have an idea ? Thank you a lot

Comment: Are you here @wentjun ??

Comment: @OrenCohen yes I am here! I have changed res.length to res1.length and res2.length respectively. does it still give you the errors?

Comment: i alwready do this for res1.length, but the problem is that i think the browser doesn't enter in the forkJoin because i put console.log(res1) and console.log(res2) and the browser doesn't display in the console. you have an idea ?

Comment: Sorry @wentjun, i'm new on Angular so i don't know all function.

Comment: @OrenCohen don't worry :) Hmm.. May I know what are your Angular and RxJS versions?

Comment: "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.5.2"

Comment: Hmmm.. I have no idea why this won't work. In theory, this should work perfectly..

Comment: forkJoin(this.perturbationsBDD, this.trajetFavorisBDD).subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
              console.log(res1);
              console.log(res2);

Comment: @OrenCohen nope, no problem at all. Did you import forkJoin? Also, try this instead? `forkJoin(this.perturbationsBDD, this.trajetFavorisBDD).subscribe((res) => { console.log(res); } `

Comment: yes i import forkJoin, with only res dont work also. maybe this.perturbbationsBDD and this.trajetFavorisBDD must have a special type during initialization ?

Comment: for now, my declaration is that : trajetFavorisBDD: Observable<any>;
    perturbationsBDD: Observable<any>; and my initalization is that : this.trajetFavorisBDD = this.firestoreService.getTrajetFavoris().valueChanges();
                this.perturbationsBDD = this.firestoreService.getPerturbation().valueChanges();

Comment: Can you try subcribing and returning the values from both requests from firestore? And see if any values are printed? And check your network console to see if the requests are fired?

Comment: yes because if i do this : this.perturbationsBDD.subscribe((res) => {
              console.log(res); }), the browser display res value

Comment: @OrenCohen I think I got it. How about you use `combineLatest` instead of forkJoin?

Comment: i dont know this function but i can test

Comment: @OrenCohen can read more about it here. Meanwhile you will need to import it as well. `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 1):

Please console log in subscribe block or make async function

```
 this.trajetFavorisBDD.subscribe((res) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        console.log(res[i].numero);
        this.numeroTrajetFavorite.push({
           numero : res[i].numero
        });
    }
    console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite); // display the data
    console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite[0].numero)
 })
```

Comment: numeroPerturbationsFavorite: Array<{numero: any}> = [];
    numeroTrajetFavorite: Array<{numero: any}> = [];

Comment: Please your console.log() in timeout 5 sec  and check

Comment: i send a picture of console log in my question

Comment: no it's not that i want.
i just want to make the 'for' loop work

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how asynchronous calls work in Javascript.

1. To make the `for loop` work, it has to be executed after the async call is completed,
   which means it has to be within the callbacks of `subscribe`
2. If you try to loop outside `subscribe`, since `numeroPerturbationsFavorite.length` will always be `0` before async call is complete, for loop will be executed with `no iterations`.
3. And the reason you see array displayed in `console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite)` is, your browser immediately updates it when the value changes (or set) for an array after the async complete (iff: The array is not expanded (viewed) by the user within the console)
4. But in case of `console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite[0].numero)`, the array items are not updated (or printed) by the browser, since you are trying to access the array items before async call is complete.

Suggestion:

Move your for loop inside the `subscribe`, or create a separate function and call it from the `subscribe`

```
this.trajetFavorisBDD.subscribe(res => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        console.log(res[i].numero);
        this.numeroTrajetFavorite.push({
          numero: res[i].numero
        });
      }
      this.myFunc()
});

myFunc() {
    console.log(this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite); // display the data
    console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite); // display the data
    console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite[0].numero); //display undefined

    for (let i = 0; i < this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite[i].numero); // dont display

      for (let a = 0; a < this.numeroTrajetFavorite.length; a++) {
        console.log(this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite[i].numero); // dont display
        console.log(this.numeroTrajetFavorite[i].numero); // dont display
        if (
          this.numeroPerturbationsFavorite[i].numero ===
          this.numeroTrajetFavorite[a].numero
        ) {
          this.isPerturbationsFavorite = true;
          console.log(this.isPerturbationsFavorite); // dont display
        } else {
          this.isPerturbationsFavorite = false;
          console.log(this.isPerturbationsFavorite); // dont display
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but the problem is that i want also the numeroPerturbationsFavorite array. And if i do like you suggest me, i have the numeroTrajetFavorite array but no numeroPerturbationsFavorite. Did you have an another suggestion do get the two array outside the subscribe ?